# Replace all spaces with an underscore in the selected block

Tags: vim

I want to replace all spaces with an underscore, in the currently highlighted block i.e. not to apply it on the entire page.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 14):

When in visual mode type:

```
:s/\%V /_/g
```

see http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/VimTip438

Comment: From the linked page: In order to actually search within the visual selection, you will need to use the \%V atom, or use the markers defined by the visual selection with the \%>'< and \%<'> atoms. This is best done by leaving the visual selection with <Esc> before entering your search. You may want to consider a mapping to automatically leave visual selection and enter the appropriate atoms.

Comment: this actually throws an error when no spaces are present in the selection, thus, it cannot be used in a macro for example

Answer (score 1):

You could go into visual mode (by typing v while in command mode) and then select the required text and thereafter enter the command mode (by typing ":"). This will automatically insert the selection range and then you could perform the necessary substitution.

- Go to visual mode by typing v
- Select the necessary text.
- Type : to enter command mode. You would find in the prompt below **:'<,'>**
- The final command would look like this **:'<,'>s/ /_/g**

Comment: this does not work. With this you will replace all spaces from the first line of the selection to the last line. If the selection starts in the middle of the line all spaces before are replaced, too.